# Move tempo signature up from staff

Tags: lilypond

In the code example below, I'd like to move the tempo signature "Slow 80" on the sheet music a little bit up. Is this possible?

```
\header {
  title = "test"
  subtitle = "123"
  composer = "my self"
  % Remove default LilyPond tagline
  tagline = ##f
}

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "a4")
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
  }
}
\relative c''
 {\tempo "Slow" 4 = 80
 a b e (f) f g d2 f g e a b a b1 c d e f \bar"||"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following line of code before the `\tempo` command:

`\override Score.MetronomeMark.Y-offset = X`

Where `X = <number of staff spaces to adjust in vertical direction>`

See also: [LilyPond Internals Reference — 3.1.76 MetronomeMark](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/internals/metronomemark)